# Nextjs axios call takes a while after setting state to take action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I have a NextJS project that uses Axios for API calls. I have a loading state which changes the button text to a loading spinner when making calls.

Im finding that when i click the button, it goes off to the api, stops the loading spinner but doesnt take action (return error message, log user in etc) for another 2 seconds or so.. If i take the login form for example, the following is called when the submit button is pressed;

```
const submitForm = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    setLoading(true)

    try {
        await login({
            email,
            password,
            remember: shouldRemember,
            setErrors,
            setStatus
        })
    } finally {
        setLoading(false)
    }
}
```

The actual login functionality looks like so;

```
const login = async ({ setErrors, setStatus, ...props }) => {
    await csrf()

    setErrors([])
    setStatus(null)

    axios
        .post('/login', props)
        .then(() => mutate())
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error

            setErrors(error.response.data.errors)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post` method from the `axios` library is asynchronous. In the above code, because it is used without the `await` keyword, the execution is backgrounded while the `login` function returns. This results in the finally block running before either the `then` or the `catch` block inside the login function are run.

Perhaps using `await` before the `axios.post()` call in the login function is what you want.